# Integrating Amazon Ads into Admob Mediation via Custom Events

Tags: admob, interstitial, amazon-advertising-api

Amazon is doing a promotion of $6 eCPM for interstitial ads in Sep, Oct, Nov. I'm wondering if anyone has successfully integrated Amazon Ad into your Admob Mediation using custom events. Amazon's website only shows how to show their ads first and fallback onto another ad network if the ad loads fail but I want to have to option to change the eCPM in admob so it serves the highest earning ad network after their promotion is over.

Comment: did you find out how to implement a custom even?